# Get Google Sign In Profile Info From Access Token - Golang

Tags: go, google-signin

I have the following JavaScript code

```
auth2.grantOfflineAccess().then(function(codeData) {
    if (!codeData) {
        alert("Something went wrong");
        return;
    }

    $.post("/do/signIn/google", codeData, function() { ... });
});
```

I am sending the code for a Google sign in to my golang web app.
I successfully got an access token from `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`.

My issue is, I am unable to get the user's profile information (such as email, display name etc.)

I've tried sending a request to `GET https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile?access_token=xxx` and I receive an empty response (blank body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must decode the Google ID token returned by `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` to convert it into a Google+ ID then you may use `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/[gplusID]?access_token=[accessToken]`

> Using Go, you can decode the google ID token using the following
>   function. Normally, it is critical that you validate an ID token
>   before you use it, but since you are communicating directly with
>   Google over an intermediary-free HTTPS channel and using your Client
>   Secret to authenticate yourself to Google, you can be confident that
>   the token you receive really comes from Google and is valid. If your
>   server passes the ID token to other components of your app, it is
>   extremely important that the other components validate the token
>   before using it.

Using Go, you can decode the ID token with the following function.

```
func decodeGoogleIDToken(idToken string) (gplusID string, err error) {
    var set struct {
        Sub string
    }
    if idToken != "" {
        // Check that the padding is correct for a base64decode
        parts := strings.Split(idToken, ".")
        if len(parts) < 2 {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Malformed ID token")
        }
        // Decode the ID token
        s := parts[1]
        switch len(s) % 4 {
        case 2:
            s += "=="
        case 3:
            s += "="
        }

        b, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(s)
        if err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Malformed ID token: %v", err)
        }
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &set)
        if err != nil {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Malformed ID token: %v", err)
        }
    }
    return set.Sub, nil
}
```

Check out an example here at https://play.golang.org/p/M7sYmE2ztx